# How to send the some string from One device to another with help of BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am totally new for BLE technology. I just want to pass some string from one Android devices to another Android devices just like one device is peripheral and another is central like master and slave thing. How can I do this?

Comment: This question does not have enough detail for Stack Overflow. I will try to close it as Too Broad.